# How can I connect the local minimum-value points between a series of curves by dotted lines?

Tags: plotting

I have a set of [data](http://www.wikiupload.com/N28FGSVGRLJJZWX) obtained by NDSolve. After I plot it, I want to indicate some feature of the curves. For example, I want to link the local minimum-value points between these curves by dotted line to highlight the track.
First, I import the data:

```
data1 = Import["C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\data1.dat"];
data2 = Import["C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\data2.dat"];
data3 = Import["C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\data3.dat"];
```

then, plot them

```
g1 = ListLinePlot[data1];
g2 = ListLinePlot[data2];
g3 = ListLinePlot[data3];
Show[g1, g2, g3, PlotRange -> All]
```

I get the following plot

[image]

What I want to do is to link the local min-value point by dashed line. Is there any simply method by *Mathematica* to do this job? Should I make use of `FindMinimum` and `FindMinValue`, but I don't know how to combine them. The objective I want to obtain is as follows which is got by hand:).
[image]

Yes, as answered by @Oska, whose code can handle many cases. But fail to treat the following case in which there are several local minimum-value points in a single curve.
This is the [my_data](http://www.wikiupload.com/BBYTW18SGZ9YJBC).

Using Oska's code

```
data1 = Import["C:\\...\\plot1_4sqrt(2)pi.dat"];
data2 = Import["C:\\...\\plot2_4sqrt(2)pi.dat"];
data3 = Import["C:\\...\\plot3_4sqrt(2)pi.dat"];

mins = Function[d, 
d[[#]] & /@ (Sort[
   First@First@
       Position[d, #] & /@ (RankedMin[Last /@ d, #] & /@ {1, 
       2})])] /@ {data1, data2, data3};
ListLinePlot[{data1, data2, data3}, 
Epilog -> {Arrowheads[0.02], 
Arrow /@ (Thread@{(First /@ mins), 
    RotateLeft@(First /@ mins)})[[;; -2]], 
Arrow /@ (Thread@{(Last /@ mins), 
    RotateLeft@(Last /@ mins)})[[;; -2]]}
]
```

I will get
[image]

As can be seen, the code fails to find the local min-value points on the first curve. What I try to get is as follow. I am confusing that why the code can find the local min-value point of the other two curves but fails to the first curve?
[image]

Comment: You should consider doing a little bit of work and find the minima that you desire on your own.

Comment: Yes, @Öskå. Thanks a LOT :). But could you give me some hints on why this code can not find the two local min-value points of the first curve but can find that of the other two similar curves.

Comment: You may consider searing on _mathematica.SE_: see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=find+local+minima) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will let you play with the style but here is a beginning:

```
data1 = Import["~/Downloads/data/data1.dat"];
data2 = Import["~/Downloads/data/data2.dat"];
data3 = Import["~/Downloads/data/data3.dat"];
mins = Function[d, 
   d[[#]] & /@ (Sort[
      First@First@Position[d, #] & /@ (RankedMin[Last /@ d, #] & /@ {1, 2})])] /@ 
   {data1, data2, data3}

ListLinePlot[{data1, data2, data3}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Line[First /@ mins], Line[Last /@ mins]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Regarding the series of arrows:

```
ListLinePlot[{data1, data2, data3}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, 
   Arrow /@ (Thread@{(First /@ mins), RotateLeft@(First /@ mins)})[[;; -2]], 
   Arrow /@ (Thread@{(Last /@ mins), RotateLeft@(Last /@ mins)})[[;; -2]]},]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, @Oska! Is there any possible to add a series of arrows on the redline? I tried this code `p0 = ListLinePlot[{data1, data2, data3}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Dashing[0.02], Line[First /@ mins], 
    Line[Last /@ mins]}];p0 /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0, .05, .05, 0}], Arrow[x]}`. But I also added arrows on the three curve where I do not need arrow.

Comment: @lxy Please check the update :)

Comment: Hi,@Oska,thank you for your helpful answer. But it might have a bug.  I am confusing that why the code can find the local min-value point of the some curves but fails to the other curves? Could you pls see my post again which has been updated. Thank you for your time!